# webview memory leak in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

How to avoid memory leak of webview
**when i close webview window memory is not release which is consume by webview**. 
i am tried many solutions from existing answers like
1. load blank page in webview
2. stop loading
3. webview=nil
4. delegate=nil
5. clear cache
6. clear cookies

Comment: can you add your code and error log where you see memory issue?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in code. i just want to other ways(rather than mention above) to release memory consume by webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is amazing that the memory leak occurs in Mac OS befor 10.12, such as 10.11, 10.11.

Although the webview dealloc normally, the occupied memory only release half and the app memory still remain heigh.

However, the occupied memory in OS 10.12 & 10.13 is entirely releaase after the webview dealloc

Comment: However, the occupied memory in OS 10.12 & 10.13 is entirely releaase after the webview dealloc...have tested this on sierra and high sierra